# Difference between JB4A SDK and Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK for iOS

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

I am trying to implement the Mobile push functionality to my app and use the marketing cloud to send pushes to my users.

However, currently my app has a JB4A SDK and I would like to upgrade to the latest and greatest that salesforce has to offer.

How do I choose between these two SDKs which seemingly do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

The new SDK (version 5.0.0 and later) for iOS is our mainline, fully supported, modern architecture SDK framework. No new work (or maintenance) will be done in the JB4A iOS static library.

Furthermore, no compatibility with future OS versions will be ensured or supported with JB4A.

See https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/ for all the details.